# Toggle org-html-head-include- only when publishing

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I use `org-mode` to publish a blog which is based on org files in a particular directory. I've customized values in *html-head*, *html-preamble*, and *html-postamble* with some Bootstrap code to get the desired html code marked up and everything works well. Accordingly, I've set `org-html-head-include-default-style` and `org-html-head-include-scripts` to `nil`.

I also sometimes use `org-mode` to export files in other locations to html which I may sometimes share (e.g., with coworkers). However, because I've set `org-html-head-include-default-style` and `org-html-head-include-scripts` to `nil`, those exports are boring (lack HTML tags that are included by default). I'd like to toggle `org-html-head-include-default-style` and `org-html-head-include-scripts` depending on where I'm publishing from (e.g., `nil` when exporting from my blog directory, other `t` when exporting from anywhere else). How do I achieve this?

My `org-mode` config is something like the following:

```
(setq org-html-htmlize-output-type 'css)
(setq org-html-head-include-default-style nil)
(setq org-html-head-include-scripts nil)

(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("orgfiles"
         :base-directory "~/blog/content/"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "/ssh:user@blog.com#22:/blog/"
         :recursive t
         :html-head "<!-- 3rd party css and js -->
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://blog.com/site/3rdParty.css\"/>
<script src=\"https://blog.com/site/3rdParty.js\"></script>

<!-- Site css and js -->
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"https://blog.com/site/site.css\"/>
<script src=\"https://blog.com/site/site.js\"></script>"
         :html-preamble "... preamble code ..."
         :html-postamble "... postamble code ...")))
```

Do I need to create some function (to toggle `org-html-head-include-default-style` and `org-html-head-include-scripts`) and a hook for `org-publish` depending on my present working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use directory-local variables for this: do `C-h i g(emacs)Per-directory local variables RET` to find out more information.

Briefly, create a file named `.dir-locals.el` in your blog directory where the Org mode files that you publish are kept. Put the following in the file:

```el
((org-mode . ((org-html-head-include-default-style . nil)
              (org-html-head-include-scripts . nil))))
```

Every Org mode file in that directory will have those two variables locally set to `nil`. Other Org mode files in other directories will not be affected.